# Three.js: Interpreting renderer.info.render output

Tags: three.js

I'm looking at one of the Google Arts Experiments [[link to page](https://artsexperiments.withgoogle.com/curatortable/#2784.97,854.68,1938.89,2784.97,-1.00,754.76)] that renders many images in a browser with WebGL + GLSL. I'm puzzled, though, by the fact that this scene includes 1,167,858 vertices and 389,286 quad faces, which equals 3 vertices per quad face (we see these numbers if we run `renderer.info.render` in the console on this page).

My question is: How in GLSL can one build or represent a quad face given fewer than 4 vertices? I'd be very grateful for any suggestions others can offer on this question!

More generally, are there tools one can use to investigate the ways a given page is using vertices, faces, and textures? I'd love to be able to really study the above-linked page as thoroughly as possible, so any tools that can help with this task would be very helpful!

Comment: Requests for tools are considered off-topic. `4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` --[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Both Chrome and Firefox have easy-to-find tools/extensions for debugging shaders, and they both work relatively well.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. In OpenGL, "face" is synonymous with "triangle". Which has 3 vertices.

Comment: @duhaime: I don't understand. You said that `renderer.info.render` shows you a 3:1 ratio between vertices and faces. That's what you *ought to see*. Why would you not trust it?

Comment: Have you considered reading a book on graphics? Not that [tag:three.js] is of super good quality, it's already horrible as is, but at this rate it seems like you will hijack ALL of the questions, and they may make very little sense if any at all.

Comment: `My question is: How in GLSL can one build or represent a face given fewer than 4 vertices?` <- GLSL has nothing to do with representing faces, at least in WebGL without compute shaders i believe. **All the faces** are built and represented **all the time** with **fewer than 4 vertices** so the question is non-sensical. It would make more sense if you asked how to make this with 4 vertices, not the other way around.

Comment: @TheJim01 it's been a while since ive seen a tool though for chrome. Firefox has some great tools.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? Can you please leave a note?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The renderer.info.render isn't neccesarily 100 percent accurate. It only accumulates stats that it can gather with minimal overhead since the stats gathering is enabled all the time.. so take any discrepancies with a grain of salt. Also that demo is using InstancedBufferGeometry. Geometry instancing works differently than classical rendering.. in that the vertex stream is just used to parametize each instance of the rectangle.. so those 3 vertices are probably used to derive the rectangle width/height/uv coordinate and position.

In summary, you can use instancing to instance a bunch of rectangles and only have to specify the parameters that make it different.. i.e. position/tex coord/scaling, etc.

Comment: thanks very much. I'm looking for a good beginner's guide to InstancedBufferGeometry -- do you know of one?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up learning the basics from this great repository: https://github.com/nicoptere/FluffyPredator